# Passing data to the MasterViewController in a SplitViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to add a `SplitViewController` so that the `TableViewController` becomes the Master and the `DetailViewController` becomes the Detail in the Split View. Here's an example of how my project was set up before adding the split view.

[image]

The problem is I have a `ViewController` for a `CollectionView` which passes data to the `TableView`. By adding a `SplitViewController` I then cannot pass data to the `TableView` when segueing from the `CollectionViewController`.

So this is how the project is set up when adding the SplitViewController.

[image]

How can I pass data from the `CollectionViewController` to the `SplitViewController` Master / `TableViewController` ?

Comment: What type is your segue's destinationViewController?

Comment: @Gordonium From the `CollectionView` to the `SplitViewController` it is - Show (e.g Push)

Comment: Would you be happy to share your project with me? It might be easier to debug.

Comment: Do you understand my question, the problem I am finding is I can't use a PrepareForSegue method from the CollectionViewController to the TableViewController because now I have to segue to the SplitViewController.

Comment: Ah right. Which class have you set as the TableView's delegate/data source?

Comment: I have set it to the TableViewController (The master in the split view) and have all the methods in the class file TableViewController.swift to output the data. Of course theres no data because nothing has been passed to the controller.

Comment: You have many options here but a couple stand out. First pass the data through each controller A -> B -> C. Or, make use of a Model class (as in MVC) and provide access to your data model.

Comment: How would you suggest doing this ? All I have done is add a split view controller between the `CollectionViewController` & the `TableViewController` (Master). I have left the files the same and changed the segue to the `SplitViewController` instead of directly to the `TableViewController`. I am knew to iOS development but this seems a pretty easy procedure but I cannot find any resources where the split view controller has another ViewController before it that passes the data to the table.